# mongodb c# driver How to insert nested entity with generated id

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-csharp-2.0

I'm trying to insert nested entity, it's create the nested entity but its id remains null.
i cant find an answer or example anywhere else. please help me.

what i did?

i have 2 objects

```
menu
{
   Id
   items[]
}

Item
{
   Id
}
```

i mapped the two objects's id with

```
map.AutoMap();
map.SetIdMember(CreateIdMapper(map.GetMemberMap(p => p.Id)));

protected BsonMemberMap CreateIdMapper(BsonMemberMap bsonMemberMap)
{
   return bsonMemberMap
      .SetIdGenerator(StringObjectIdGenerator.Instance)
      .SetSerializer(CreateStringSerializer());
}

protected StringSerializer CreateStringSerializer()
{
    return new StringSerializer(BsonType.ObjectId);
}
```

this is the update

```
var filter = Builders<Menu>.Filter.Eq(x => x.Id, menu.Id);
var update = Builders<Menu>.Update.AddToSet(x=>x.Items, item);   


await m_mongoClientProvider.GetCollection<Menu>(MongoCollection.Menu)
                .UpdateOneAsync(filter, update);
```

What am i doing wrong?
thanks

Comment: So, your problem is that the nested Item object has a null Id? If that's your question then: MongoDB will only generate the _id for the primary key field, in your case the Id for Menu. Since Item is a nested type of Menu Mongo will not automatically generate its Id, since it is only a nested object. You are responsible for creating an Id for it.